# Cookie Not Being Set on Netlify Hosted React App

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, cookies, cross-domain, netlify

I have a React app that calls into a Rails App.

The React app is hosted on Netlify, and the Rails app on Heroku.

Locally, I am able to create a session and have the rails app set a cookie in the browser.

The network requests work just fine. However, after deploying to Netlify the production app isn't setting cookies.

Here is my login function

```
    fetch(`${API_ROOT}/api/sessions`, {
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      method: 'post',
      credentials: 'include',
      withCredentials: true,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.status === 'created' && data.user){
        props.handleLogin(data)
        navigate("/");
      } else
      {
        setAuthErrorState({
          isError: true,
          message: data.message
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

And my session_store.rb and cors.rb files

cors (domain redacted)

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins "http://localhost:3000"
    resource "*", headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head],
    credentials: true
  end

  allow do
    origins "https://www.[domain].io"
    resource "*", headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head],
    credentials: true
  end
end
```

session_store.rb

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_authentication_app"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would request you to go to the "Network" tab in the dev tools of your browser and go to the request :'${API_ROOT}/api/sessions', and and confirm 2 things in the response headers of this request:

1. Is your React app domain name(i.e,: "https://www.[domain].io") present in the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` of the response? If not, what is the header set to ?
2. Is the said cookie present in the `Cookie` header of the response ? If not, please mention.

Purpose of this activity: To pinpoint the issue to either a CORS red flag by the browser , or the cookie not having the proper domain name set in it, and hence the cookie might appear to **vanish**.

Comment: I realized I had to set the samesite to none on the rails side

Comment: Based on the article above, where it also says Chrome automatically disables same site cookies, it looks like the real answer is just to put the server and frontned on the same site, no? I'm having the same issue and without tinkering with the browser settings, none of the "sameSite" settings work because... Chrome strips it and I don't expect all my users to change their Chrome settings for my app

Answer (score 0):

This post helped me resolve the issue:

https://medium.com/@ArturoAlvarezV/use-session-cookies-to-authenticate-a-user-with-a-rails-api-backend-hosted-in-heroku-on-one-domain-f702ddf8c07